# Load YouTube video with AS3 Adobe AIR

Tags: javascript, actionscript-3, youtube, air

As we all know, the Youtube API for ActionScript has been discontinued. So, I looked for alternatives to run the Youtube videos in my Adobe AIR application.

I tested those codes. Below is what happened to each one.

**1° Code:**

```
var hl:HTMLLoader = new HTMLLoader();
hl.width = 500;
hl.height = 300;
hl.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, complete); //event is dispatched, but with js errors
hl.load(new URLRequest("http://www.youtube.com/embed/XXXXX"));
```

<sup>**Result:** The error 'Object.freeze is not a function' occours</sup>

**2° Code:**

```
var webView:StageWebView = new StageWebView();
webView.viewPort = new Rectangle(0, 0, stage.stageWidth, stage.stageHeight);
webView.stage = stage;
webView.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, complete); //event is dispatched, but with js errors
webView.loadURL("http://www.youtube.com/embed/XXXXX");
```

<sup>**Result:** The same error 'Object.freeze is not a function' occours.</sup>

**3° Code:**

```
// changed 'useNative' param to true for StageWebView
var webView:StageWebView = new StageWebView(true);
// the same code of 2° Code
```

<sup>**Result:** No errors, but the page does not load fully and the video don't play.</sup>

**4° Code:**

```
// I've changed loadURL to loadString, for both methods...
var stringPage:String = '<html><head></head><body><iframe width="640" height="360" src="http://youtube.com/embed/XXXXXX" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe></body></html>';
webView.loadString(stringPage);
// or
hl.loadString(stringPage);
```

<sup>**Result:** A black rectangle appears, but the video don't load.</sup>

**5° Code:**

```
// I've tried use the AS3 API URL:
hl.load(new URLRequest("http://www.youtube.com/v/XXXXXX"));
// or
webView.loadURL("http://www.youtube.com/v/XXXXXX");
```

<sup>**Result:** A message "Flash-embedded videos are no longer supported" appears and Video don't play.</sup>

**"Stranger Things":**

```
// the Youtube Page Video works!
webView.loadURL("http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XXXXXX");
// or
hl.load(new URLResquest("http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XXXXXX"));
```

**The question is: someone knows how to load a Youtube Video with ActionScript 3.0 in this year 2019?**

Answer (score 0):

Try a basic embed (no `autoplay` and `allowAccelorometer`etc):

Also rather than mix `"` with `'`, instead just un-escape the `"` quotes where needed.
eg:  `width=\"640\"` gives String of `width="640"`

so:

```
'<html><head></head><body><iframe width="640" ... '; 

//should be written as...
"<html><head></head><body><iframe width=\"640\" ... ";
```

**Code 4:** (untested)

```
// I've changed loadURL to loadString, for both methods...
var stringPage:String = "<html><head></head><body><iframe width=\"640\" height=\"360\" src=\"http://youtube.com/embed/XXXXXX\" frameborder=\"0\" </iframe></body></html>";
webView.loadString(stringPage);
// or
hl.loadString(stringPage);
```

I hope that little detail is what fixes it and gives correct Youtube loading.

**PS:** 
Another option is to just access the direct MP4 from Youtube server (skip Youtube player embedding).

Let me know if you're interested in direct links (you'll have to make your own AS3 player controls).

Comment: This did not work... The same errors occours... Can you show me how I access the mp4 from youtube server? Probably with NetStream, NetConnection and Video objects?